# How to properly implement MapBox SDK to Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, mapbox

I am trying to implement MapBox SDK to my Android Application. I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/) but I am getting this error.

> Unable to resolve dependency for
> ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
> com.mapbox.maps:android:10.6.1.

I have tried following the [legacy documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/legacy/maps/guides/install/), but still no luck. I would like to ask if there are any other ways to implement the SDK or did I miss something. TYIA.

Here are my gradle scripts:

build.gradle (Project Level)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins
{
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false

}

allprojects {

    final def var = repositories
            {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis' }
        maven { url 'https://olympus.esri.com/artifactory/arcgisruntime-repo/' }
                maven {
                    url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
                    authentication {
                        basic(BasicAuthentication)
                    }
                    credentials {
                        // Do not change the username below.
                        // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                        username = "mapbox"
                        // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                        password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
                    }
                }

    }
    var
    
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("dependencies"))
        {
            dependencies {
                implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1"
                implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0"
                implementation "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:$arcgisVersion"
                implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
            }
        }
        project.android {

            defaultConfig {
                multiDexEnabled true
            }
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete)
{
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module level)

```
plugins
{
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

ext {
    arcgisVersion = '100.13.0'
}

android
{
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig
    {
        applicationId "com.example.project1"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes
    {
        release
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions
    {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures
    {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies
 {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

     implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
     implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat"
     implementation "com.google.android.material:material"
     implementation "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android"
     implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex"

     implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.6.0'


     implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.6.1'


     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"


 }
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()



    }
}


rootProject.name = "proect1"
include ':app'
```

Comment: add `jcenter()` repository inside `repositories` in your `settings.gradle` file .

Comment: Thanks @VaibhavGoyal Unfortunately, after adding jcenter() inside the repositories in settings.gradle, the error persists.

Comment: I haven't used Native Android Development quite a lot of time so maybe try adding it inside `all projects`.